# Fast algorithm to test if axis aligned rects cover another rect

Tags: algorithm, spatial, computational-geometry

We have axis aligned rect as: `{ top, left, width, height: number}`
We want to test given:

- a list of axis aligned rects `rs`
- an axis aligned rect: `r`

if `r` is entirely covered by the **union** of `rs`.

What's the fastest way to do this?

What I have found is there are fast data structures to test intersections of `rs` and `r` (e.g. https://github.com/mourner/rbush), so I can first find what rects in `rs` intersect with `r` and then subtract from `r` all these rects, and see if you have any remained area. This seems to work well if `rs` has not much overlapping, because you don't end up with a lot of intersecting rects.

Any better solutions?

Comment: What language are you using? It would be helpful to state it in your question's tags

Comment: @YvesDaoust people can't recommend libraries or tools if they don't know what language you are using. I was going to suggest taking a look at Python's Shapely and Geopandas libraries but it seems you are using javascript.

Comment: @motrix: an algorithm is NOT a library. Suggesting a language is a nonsense and blindly using ready-made APIs is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a scanline process.

Sort all rectangles by the ordinate of the top edge. Then move from top edge to top edge, keeping a list of "active rectangles" updated (i.e. all rectangles that cross the current horizontal).

Consider the horizontal extent covered by these rectangles between two successive horizontals, and check if they full cover the corresponding slice of the target rectangle.